# How to retrieve the attribute from event object of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a web application. In my app I am using jQuery. But I am having a problem or a thing that I am so curious with jQuery that is I want to retrieve the attribute of event object not using $(this).

This is formal way

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('attribute')) // I am retrieving attribute using $(this)
})
```

But this is what I want

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(e){
  alert(e.attr('attribute')) // I am retrieving from e
})
```

I think you understand my second code. That is how I want to retrieve using event object. Is that possible?

Comment: Need HTML and the specific attribute targeted (e.g. `data-*`, `height`, `class`, `name`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

`e` in your code is just the [event object (interface)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

You're probably looking for the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and you'd have to wrap that in jQuery to use `attr()`

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(e){
    alert( $(e.target).attr('attribute') );
});
```

Comment: It always undefined.

Comment: What attribute are you trying to get, and does the element you click have that attribute? `event.target` is the element you actually click, not the one bound in the event handler.